# Set the height of a list item to that of two lines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

When using a RecyclerView, is it possible to set the item height to be that of two text lines?

Suppose an item has a TextView on it. Some items might have a long text that does not fit in one line. I will restrict the maximum number of lines to 2. However, if some items have 1-line height and others have 2-line height, it would look ugly. Therefore, I want all items to have the height of 2-lines, even though the item has only one line of text.

I can set height of an item in DP, but the problem is that since I use system font settings, hard-coding a numeric value for height should be bad. Some systems may have large fonts with large margins.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a option you can set minimum height of textView. `android:minHeight="50dp"` or you can add this `android:lines="2"` to your xml code.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:lines="2"/>
```

Now `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` will manage font size.. 20sp or 50sp or any size of system font it wouldn't be a problem..

Hope it helps

Answer (score 12):

have you tried: android:lines="2" in xml?
according to doc:
Makes the TextView be exactly this many lines tall.